# Schedule a duplicate rule?

Tags: apex, administration, duplicate-management, scheduled-job

Does anyone know a way to schedule duplicate rules? We want the duplicate rule to be during business hours and then turned inactive in the evening to import.

Comment: How complicated are the duplicate rules you want to schedule?

Comment: There is no out of the box functionality for this.  If you have a specific username that is used for imports only, you could set the rule criteria to exclude the user completely from the rule.